# What happened to the "<script defer>" hack in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

A few years ago Dean Edwards brought us [this workaround](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/09/busted/) to the `document.onload` problem. The IE version of the solution involved appending this snippet to the document:

```
<script defer src=ie_onload.js><\/script>;
```

Dean was also pretty adamant on the fact that this was the closest solution to perfection he could find and dismissed any solution that involved the `onreadystatechange` attribute as being unreliable (see comments).

[Subsequent refinements](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/) on his solution still involved some version of <script defer> and most JS framework implemented it, including jQuery.

Today, I'm perusing JQuery 1.4.1's source and I can't find it.

At which point was it dropped and why?

Comment: Interesting question, +1.  FWIW, I was playing around with using `defer` for document readiness on the local file system recently and found that it fired too early sometimes, but I don't know if that's the answer.

Comment: The current version of jQuery is 1.4.2 by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was removed in the jQuery 1.2.2 release, [you can find the release notes here](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2.2).

> Internet Explorer document ready drastically improved. We use a new technique inspired by Diego Perini. It allows us to not have to do a `document.write()` anymore, which is really fantastic.

[Here's the 1.2.1 Version](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.2.1/src/event.js#L437) vs [the 1.2.2 version](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.2.2/src/event.js#L501).

The main motivation was to remove the `document.write` and avoid the problem of IE *still* triggering the `ready` a bit too early, so [now it's completely rewritten](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L433) to listen to `onreadystatechange` (in IE) and fall-back to `window.onload` if all else fails.